# "Connect timeout" in spring ws and still survive?

Tags: spring, web-services, error-handling

Spring 3.2.6

There might be an easy solution for this that I've missed, but I've been scouring the boards for the last couple days, tried a few things and so far nothing - so I thought I'd consult the experts.

My app:
I have 5 `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` beans configured in my `applicationContext.xml` that connect to and consume various web services.  Everything works fine, very nice!

Problem:
When my app starts there may be 1 or more web services that are either OFF or not accessible.  This is fine as my app can run without them; however, is there a way to continue processing other beans in the context after receiving a `TimeoutException` (or any Exception due to connectivity with the WS)?

I was hoping for a property in `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` like `continueOnError` or something similar.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the lookup/check of the web service at startup by setting the `lookupServiceOnStartup` property to false.

```
<bean id="yourService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="lookupServiceOnStartup" value="false" />
    // Other properties
</bean>
```

Advantage your application starts up a bit faster, drawback the first call to the web service might take a little longer.

You can check the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.html) for more information, the [`lookupServiceOnStartup` property](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.6.RELEASE/index.html?org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.html) is defined on the `JaxWsPortClientInterceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use `setLookupServiceOnStartup` and set it to false.

http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework/spring-web/3.2.6.RELEASE/index.html?org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.html